# How do I save the oldvalue if the input name is variable?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

The oldvalue is usually set with the *name* attribute, in my case the *name* attribute is variable depending on the id **name="option{{$question->id}}"**, so I can't find the way to save and load the olvalue, this is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="option{{$question->id}}" id="question" autocomplete="off" value="1" data-oldvalue="{{old('option'.$question->id) }}"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="option{{$question->id}}" id="question" autocomplete="off" value="0" data-oldvalue="{{old('option'.$question->id) }}"> No
    </label>
</div>
```

Not sure if the If there is any other approach to get my oldvalues loaded (after validation errors) I would like to know.

Extra info: I'm not sure if the reason the old values don't load is the **autocomplete="off"**. So I would like to know how to alert or get my oldvalue.

Comment: I guess you can use like this **value="{{ old('option'.$question->id) }}"**

Comment: But if there's no _oldvalue_, I want it to be "1". So should I try `value="{{ old('option'.$question->id)}} ? 'option'.$question->id : 1"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the values directly and use the default value if no old value is available.

```
value="{{ old('option' . $question->id, 1) }}"
value="{{ old('option' . $question->id, 0) }}"
```